# How do i match multiple strings of a line using grep command

Tags: grep

I have to find and print only matched strings of a line in file using grep command.

Below is example text:

```
04-06-2013 INFO blah blah blah blah Param : 39 another text Ending the line.
05-06-2013 INFO blah blah allah line 2 ending here with Param : 21.
```

I want output to be printed as below after grep command

```
04-06-2013 INFO   Param : 39
04-06-2013 INFO   Param : 21
```

I tried grep command with -o option and regex `'.*INFO'`. I was successful to print both the text separately in different grep commands where as i want this in single command.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the simplest grep function you need is grep -o ".*INFO\|Param : [0-9]*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this with pure grep, as you'd need to be able to specify a regex with grouped terms, and then only print out certain regex groups rather than everything matched by the entire regex - so you'd e.g. specify `(.*INFO)(.*)(Param : [0-9]*)` as the regex and then only print groups `1` and `3` (assuming you start counting at 1).

You can however use `sed` to post-process the output for you:

```
% cat foo
04-06-2013 INFO blah blah blah blah Param : 39 another text Ending the line.
05-06-2013 INFO blah blah allah line 2 ending here with Param : 21.
% grep 'Param :' foo | sed 's/\(.*INFO\)\(.*\)\(Param : [0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1 \3/'
04-06-2013 INFO Param : 39
05-06-2013 INFO Param : 21
```

What I'm doing above is replacing the match with just groups `1` and `3`, separated by a space.

I think [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/11130/can-gnu-grep-output-a-selected-group) is related (possibly even a duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o ".*INFO\|Param : [0-9]*"
```